# next.js SSR set proxy

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js

for network reasons，nextjs Requesting API in getServerSideProps will fail，in dev，I want to configure the proxy, but I can't find a way，Is there any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install the following npm packages:

```
    "https-proxy-agent": "5.0.1",
    "net": "1.0.2",
    "tls": "0.0.1",
```

Then create `baseFetchOptions.ts`

```
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

const baseFetchOptions: any = {};
if(process.env.HTTP_PROXY) {
    const proxyUrl = new URL(process.env.HTTP_PROXY);
    baseFetchOptions.agent = new HttpsProxyAgent({
        host: proxyUrl.hostname,
        port: proxyUrl.port
    });
}

export default baseFetchOptions;
```

Now you can use it. Example:

```
  import baseFetchOptions from "@/utils/baseFetchOptions";

  const response = await fetch(
    "https://...",
    {
      ...baseFetchOptions,
      method: "POST",
    },
  );
```

If you want to test it, you can use [squid](https://hub.docker.com/r/ubuntu/squid) docker container.

```
"dev": "HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128/ next dev",
```

Comment: thank you, this solved my problem,I want to ask how to use in "next/image"